# Avoid 'parsed' type error from getParsedTransaction

Tags: typescript, error

As you can see in screenshots, I have a type error. How can I avoid this problem ?

[image: IDE Type description]

[image: IDE Type error]

The type of my transaction is 'ParsedTransactionWithMeta' from getParsedTransaction method.

Same problem with 'accounts'. Accounts exist in PartiallyDecodedInstruction, and parsed exist on ParsedInstruction
[image: IDE Accounts problem description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already figured out the type ParsedInnerInstruction uses | operator, and accounts and parsed properties are only available in one of the types.

```
type ParsedInnerInstruction = {
  instructions: (ParsedInstruction | PartiallyDecodedInstruction)[];
};
```

To fix this you can explicitly narrow down type checking using conditionals, i,e

```
const instruction = instructions[i]; 

if ('parsed' in instruction) { 
  // access parsed property
} 
if ('accounts' in instruction) { 
 // access account property
}
```

This way TS can infer the type.